# 'make' utility missing from path when trying to build discord.py[voice]

Tags: python, makefile, discord.py

I was trying to install discord.py[voice] and for the life of me I couldn't get it to work, I have tried installing make with migw32 and trough choco but nothing seems to work(yes I added them to path) any help?

```
raise Exception("ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH")
  Exception: ERROR: The 'make' utility is missing from PATH
  ----------------------------------------
  ERROR: Failed building wheel for PyNaCl
Failed to build PyNaCl
ERROR: Could not build wheels for PyNaCl which use PEP 517 and cannot be installed directly
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
apk add make
```

or

```
apt-get install make
```